# Problem importing Seaborn : module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'TIMEOUT'

Tags: jupyter

I wanted to import seaborn in Jupyter notebook but says : `No module named 'seaborn'`
and when I want to install it through pip, it says :`module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'TIMEOUT'`
Has anyone encountered the same error?

Comment: You really aren't sharing much with us here about what you are doing. How are you importing seaborn? How did you install seaborn? Where are you working (Jupyter installed on your own machine or remote)/ are you sure you aren't using JupyterLite?